# global name 'mock' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to do unit testing in Python. I keep running into problems with mock, which *should* be back ported to Python 2.7, but I can't get it to work.

At the top of the code I have: `from mock import MagicMock, call`, but I still get errors when I run the unittests where it complains `global name 'mock' is not defined`.

Frustrated, I went to see if it really was installed (pip install mock and pip install unittest have all been run).

mock.py *only* exists in `/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/mock.py`, which leads me to believe that only Python3 on Debian Jessie really, actually supports mocking objects.

So, here's the question: how do I get the actual backport for 2.7 **or** in the alternative, how do I configure Debian 8 to use Python3 by default for running applications?

Comment: To rule out silly mistakes: the error occurs on your `from mock import etc` line?

Comment: Please show the code and the full error. You are clearly referring to `mock` directly somewhere, but without showing the code we cannot help. Note, this is a question about Python syntax, not about mocking or backporting a library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.

For future searchers, the answer was two fold:

1. add `import mock`, but this causes an error because Python 2.7 libraries on Debian Jessie do not have mock.py in /usr/lib/python2.7/, so you solve that problem by:
2. Download the [latest backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock#downloads), extract it, and copy the mock directory that contains the mock package to /usr/lib/python2.7/

For some reason, pip and easy_install are only installing the 3.4 libraries.